How to calculate guessing probability for quantum key distribution?
There are 3 Projections $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$ corresponding to 3 inputs $x = 1, 2, 3$ for Alice. Similarly, the same projections are used by Bob for $y = 1, 2, 3$. Each input has 2 outcomes, $a = 1, 2$ and $b = 1, 2$ where the outcome $a = 1$ is given by using $P_x$ for measurement and $a = 2$ is given by using $I - P_x$ for measurement.
So, this gives me a quantum correlation $$P = \{P(ab|xy) \,|\, x, y \in \{1, 2, 3\}, a, b \in \{1, 2\}\}\,.$$ I have found a Bell inequality for this quantum correlation. However, now I need to find Eve's guessing probability as a noise function. I am struggling with the concept. Could someone explain how to find guessing probability?
I am mainly struggling with formulating the SDP Program to get the maximum guessing probability.
Background: I am an undergrad doing research.

It's not easy. I assume that you are working here in the device-independent scenario.
The first thing you need is to understand how the noise affects the value of the Bell inequality; this value enters as a constraint in the SDP (it's also possible to use more constraints than just the Bell value). After that you need to use an implementation of the NPA hierarchy in order to maximize Eve's guessing probability under this constraint.
This is described in a high-level way in Section VI.A.1 of this review (I'm an author), and in detail in this paper.

Very interesting. It would be great if you could give more context to your reply and perhaps write a basic formulation of  problem without referring to a paper (which looks very interesting). This would probably interest many people as well.

Feel free to do it yourself and edit the answer. I don't have this kind of time.
